# Mistakes occurred when using Xcode to compile C++ program

Tags: c++, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq0ag.png)
It's causing an Expected ';' after top level declarator, error (during build) in Xcode at this line: void intArray::writeToFile(<#char *filename#>)

I've heard that this is because Xcode add "#" to my program, is that why?And how can I remove this two "#"?

Thanks a lot.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class intArray
{
private:
int *array;
int length;
public:
intArray(char *filename);
void sort();
~intArray();
void writeToFile(char *filename);
};


intArray::intArray(char *filename)
{
ifstream myFile(filename);
int len=300;
array=new int[len];
length=0;
while(myFile>>array[length++]);
length--;
myFile.close();
}

void intArray::sort()
{
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{for(int j=i;j<length;j++)
    if(array[i]>array[j])
    {int temp;
        temp=array[i];
        array[i]=array[j];
        array[j]=temp;
}
}
}

intArray::~intArray()
{
delete [] array;
}

void intArray::writeToFile(<#char *filename#>)
{
int step=0;
ofstream outFile(filename);
for(int i=0;i<length;i+=step)
{outFile<<array[i]<<endl;
    step++;
}
outFile.close();
}

void main()
{
intArray myArray("in.dat");
myArray.sort();
myArray.writeToFile("out.dat");
}
```

Comment: void intArray::writeToFile(<#char *filename#>)
{
    int step=0;
    ofstream outFile(filename);
    for(int i=0;i<length;i+=step)
    {outFile<<array[i]<<endl;
        step++;
    }
    outFile.close();
}

Comment: What? Didn't you write that line?

Comment: ...What?I wrote that line at the beginning of my code.Well, I've posted a picture about my code simultaneously.

Comment: There's no "<#" in that code. I suspect that there's more errors than that, or you have a syntax problem earlier in the file. (And please post both code and error messages as text, not pictures.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank for your help!Now I've posted my code and the error message is "Expect ';' after a top level declarator".Could you please figure out what's wrong with it ?:)

Comment: `#` on first line should be removed.

Comment: @aichao Well I'm sorry but that '#' was just a mistake when I post my code on the internet,the code on my Xcode board didn't include that '#'.I've rectified it,thanks for informing:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally figured this one out, and it appears to be a side effect of how XCode handles its parameter suggestions, the ones you can tab between (they're normally blue, I think).

If you copy such a suggestion in XCode, it's surrounded with get the strange characters "<#" and "#>", and pasting text surrounded with those characters in XCode will turn that text blue.

If you start writing the method name, like `writeToFile`, XCode will suggest a parameter list taken from the declaration (it's shown in blue).
That text doesn't really "exist" until you've written it or accepted the suggestion, though, and until that text exists, the absence of it will cause confusing errors.

The fix should be pretty simple: put your cursor in the blue parameter list and press Enter to accept it (or write the text by hand).

Comment: Thanks for you vivid answer and fortunately it finally worked!Many thx~